# Is it possible to redirect to iframe?

Tags: javascript, php, redirect, iframe

Is it possible to redirect to iframe? The iframe URL is dynamically changed  generating each time a unique string.

Comment: add some code that you tried

Comment: Please try to add some more context to your question

Comment: Please read [tour] then [ask] then [mcve] then edit your question.  As written I can't tell what you want to do.

Comment: <iframe src="http://example.com/.........."></iframe>